# Google Analytics Version 5 - In-page analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I just upgrade to the new version of Google Analytics. Previously in version 4 we had in-page Analytics in the content reports that should a sort of heat map of clicks on the site.

Anybody knows if this has been removed or maybe moved to another section?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been recently removed by Google and the official word is that it should be back in a couple of weeks. In the meantime it's still accessible through the old interface.